# Using SSH to find access to a problematic script in logs of multiple domains

Tags: ssh, web-server, logging, scripting, dreamhost

I run several (~20) sites on a Dreamhost VPS. Lately I max my memory allocation for the VPS and I want to find the problem.

I would like to have an SSH script that will scan all the log files of all the domains and show me what object (image, php script etc) gets lots of calls.

It will count the calls in each /logs/*/http/access.log, do an descending sort and show me the top 10 across domains.

But I don't know how to do that.

Can it be done?

Can anyone suggest a script that will do that?

Comment: Please don't "cross post" -- Pick the site that best fits your question and ask it there.  See the [FAQ] (SF is the "best fit" for this question :)

Answer (score 2):

The bit where you asked for a script to "...count the calls in each /logs/*/http/access.log, do an descending sort and show me the top 10 across domains." can be achieved with this:

```
grep -o " /[^ ]*" /logs/*/http/access.log | sort | uniq -c | sort -rn | head
```

But you could get the same information out of AWStats or Google analytics.  It's really just a list of all URLs aggregated and sorted by the number of times each one was accessed.

That same pattern of Unix commands can be used to aggregate your PHP errors and Apache errors which might be more useful in your particular situation.  For instance the following:

```
grep -o " PHP.*" /logs/*/php/error.log | sort | uniq -c | sort -rn | head
```

Will find all the PHP errors from your php error log (I guessed where you might keep it.) and list the 10 most frequent ones.

Another useful one is:

```
grep -o " PHP Fatal error: Allowed memory size.*" /logs/*/php/error.log | sed 's/tried to allocate [0-9]* bytes/tried to allocate N bytes/' | sort | uniq -c | sort -rn | head
```

Which will find all your out-of-memory errors and group them together.

Comment: Thanks! One correction - extra slash before "logs/*/http/access.log"

Answer (score 0):

Rather than taking that approach, I would recommend you look into setting up a centralized logging server. You have multiple choices for doing so ranging from the old file-based storage to the more web based analysis tools that store the logs into a database and let you search through them, create charts/graphs, etc.

Here's a link to a great whitepaper from Cisco Systems that will help:

[Building Scalable Syslog Management Solutions](http://www.cisco.com/en/US/technologies/collateral/tk869/tk769/white_paper_c11-557812.html)

Answer (score -1):

Instead of this manual tricky solution, I would recommend you to use a tool like [Splunk](http://www.splunk.com) Server.

Splunk is actually an amazing log analyze, in which you can analyze logs in any possible way you want, even with alerts.

> Splunk collects, indexes and harnesses the massive volumes of valuable machine data generated by your complex IT infrastructure, whether physical, virtual or in the cloud.

Comment: Wow, this really reads just like an ad...

Comment: -1 for advertising (even if you not affiliated, it's an advertisement instead of answer)

Comment: i dont know what is wrong with some mods or people here. When i used to give only a link to some solution, that was considered wrong, when i gave some description of tool, some made is ADVERTISEMENT. dont know from which angel it looks Advertisement, rather than a Description of a solution. pretty weird.

Comment: @Frank you copied a big chunk of marketing speech text from their website. There wasn't a distinction between your answer and that text. I shortened that part.